# Is there value in having more than one verify statement in unit tests?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Is there any reason to have more than one verify statement when testing a specific functionality - ie. verify that multiple/ or no dependent methods were called?

For Example:

```
public void doSomething(int size){
  if(size < 50){
    return;
   } 
  someService.someMethod();
  anotherService.someMethod();
 }
```

To test this method

```
@Test
public void testDoSomethingWithSmallSize() throws Exception{
   testObj.doSomething(5);
   verify(someServiceMock, never()).someMethod();

  //IS THERE ANY VALUE TO VERFIYING MORE THAN ONE CALL?
  //LIKE THIS??
   verfiy(anotherServiceMock, never()).someMethod();
  }
```

Is there value to having the second verify statement or is it unnecessary because if the first statement wasn't called the second wasn't either?

Comment: "Is there value to having the second verify statement?" Yes, if you want to know that `anotherServiceMock.someMethod()` was never called. Otherwise, no.

Comment: @Andy Turner but is it necessary or can I assume it wasn't called if the first one wasn't called?

Comment: @Rosie If you're going to assume that your method does what you think it does, then you don't need to test anything at all.

Comment: @khelwood so best practice is to verify everything possible?

Comment: Imagine you wrote the test before the method was implemented. Verify whatever you think the method might do wrong.

Comment: @khelwood so in the case above if the size checking is not working correctly one verify statement would be enough because if it won't return it would call serviceMock and fail?

Comment: If you are looking at the implementation of the method and are sure it is not going to change, then it is obvious that if `size` is 5, neither method is called. **With that knowledge**, there is no point testing anything. **Putting aside that knowledge**, it is possible that an implementation of this method might call one method and not the other, so it would be sensible to verify both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify the 2 statements because your code can change.

Unit test is some kind of documentation of your code.

- Verifying both statements means that both statements MUST not be called.
- Verifying only one means that only the 1st statement MUST not be called.

If someone changes the method to call `anotherService.someMethod()` inside the `if` statement, your test will still pass with 1 verify and will fail with 2 verify.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to worry that your test should only be testing one "concept" at a time, and that it is a matter of judgment about what constitutes a test that does "too much". Your original example is a good one:

```
@Test
public void testDoSomethingWithSmallSize() throws Exception{
   testObj.doSomething(5);
   verify(someServiceMock, never()).someMethod();
   verify(anotherServiceMock, never()).someMethod();
   // GOOD: You've called one method-under-test and
   // verified two related postconditions. A perfect, small, clear test.
}
```

But it's easy to take this too far.

```
@Test
public void testDoSomethingWithAnySmallSize() throws Exception{
   testObj.doSomething(1);
   testObj.doSomething(3);
   testObj.doSomething(5);
   verify(someServiceMock, never()).someMethod();
   verify(anotherServiceMock, never()).someMethod();
   // LESS GOOD: You've called one method-under-test three times, but
   // they share postconditions and concepts. Pragmatic, but not the
   // "one test method for one test case" ideal of most frameworks.
}

@Test
public void thisShouldBeThreeTests() throws Exception{
   testObj.doSomething(7);
   verify(someServiceMock).doAThing(7);
   verify(anotherService).doAThing(700);

   testObj.doSomethingElse(9);
   verify(someServiceMock).doAThing(9);
   verify(anotherService).doAThing(900);

   testObj.doAThirdThing(12);
   verify(someServiceMock).doAThing(12);
   verify(anotherService).doAThing(1200);

   // BAD: Even though these are related, this could easily be three
   // unrelated tests for better naming and reporting, and to help you
   // identify why one case might be failing versus three. Break this up.
}
```

So yes, don't be afraid to have more than one `verify` in the same test, but do be careful not to let your `verify` statements stray to be unrelated, and be especially careful if you're resetting your test setup with Mockito's `reset` method.

Answer (score 0):

YES! Part of the function of a unit test is documenting the expected behaviors of code. The test(s) should be written in a way that treats the code under test as a black box. If the code under test will do two things in a specific order (if conditions are met) then the unit test should check that all things were done under positive conditions AND that NONE of the items were done under the negative conditions.

If you only check one condition in your test, then 2 years from now, an intern might update the code, and need to remove the one task that is being checked. Your test will still pass (code removed not executed - check!) but that doesn't mean the code is behaving correctly.